# From where would a referenced assembly's culture info be loaded? And how to set it to "neutral"?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, .net-assembly

I have a C# project to create a dll and the project is referencing the `System.ComponentModel.Composition` assembly. Building the project does not create any errors, but when running the application, it shows with the built dll and throws this error:

> Exception ::Could not load file or assembly 'System.ComponentModel.Composition.resources, Version=4.0.0.0, *Culture=en-NZ*, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I am not sure what this error means but I think that the `Culture` is not supposed to be `en-NZ`, I think it should be `neutral`. Is there a way to change that to `neutral`?

Comment: Do you think it's the Culture variable error? Isn't it simply the fact that an appropriate dll (System.ComponentModel.Composition.resources) is missing?

Comment: Yes, about that 1. The application is running properly if I use the dll that I got when I installed the application, but the application crashes if I use the dll that I built and I checked in registry about that dll, all references have culture as neutral so I suspect that could be the issue 2. I've copied the .net v4.0 folder from another system and this didn't resolve the error (I'm not sure if this is enough, I mean do I need to register the dll?)

Comment: .net 4.0 should include it by default.

Comment: I didn't mention it before but I'm building the code in windows 7 and running the application in a different system that uses XP, the XP system didn't had that specific assembly in the .net v4.0 folder

Comment: yes, .net 4.0 includes it but I think to refer to that the culture should be set to neutral